# StackExchange Election: Primary counter

Tags: script, elections

This user script adds a short overview table at the of the election page during the primary election phase on Stack Exchange moderator elections. The table lists all candidates, ordered by their current primary vote score, along with their user information.

The purpose of this is to allow keeping an eye on the votes of ongoing elections which the default interface and (deliberately) unsorted candidate list does not allow for.

### Example

The following is an example of the user script in action for [election 6](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary) on Stack Overflow:

[image: Example view for election #6]

### Install and source

- **[Click to install](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poke/9058895/raw/stackexchange-election-primary-counter.user.js)**
- [Source](https://gist.github.com/poke/9058895)
- Current version: 1.5.2 (2019-03-12 20:48 UTC)

### Changelog

- **1.5.x:** Added support for other Stack Exchange sites.
- **1.4.x:** Added the ability to query the vote count for users that have access to the tools. Also added support for https.
- **1.3.x:** Updated for new election style (as used on Stack Overflow in April 2015)
- **1.2.x:** Display withdrawn users differently
- **1.1.x:** Display user rank, reputation and flag count; visual changes; support for Scriptish’ auto-updates
- **1.0.x:** Initial release

Comment: Has something changed? It isn't working for me this time. (It worked until the last elections)

Comment: @BhargavRao Apparently, they changed the code slightly. Fixed it in v1.4.5.

Comment: Hmm, something _is_ broken. I'm pretty sure that I could expand the score into pos/neg when I clicked on them. It is not working for me now.

Comment: @BhargavRao You’re right, I missed that last night when I fixed the script. It should work now again.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The https://stackoverflow.com/election isn't matched.

In addition to:

```
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/election/*
```

it should list

```
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/election
```

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (v1.5.0)

You should probably add more include patterns for the other stacks.
If you use:

```
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/election*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/election*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/election*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/election*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/election*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/election*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/election*
```

instead of those 2 `@include`s, in the script; it will work for all SE sites -- like Information Security, for example.

Comment: Took the liberty of modifying your proposal to a single `@match` directive.  `@match` performs better and [has smarter and "safer" wildcard matching](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) than `@include`. ... Roll the edit back, if you don't like it.

Comment: Very good. I'm not an expert on user scripts after all. Good job.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot a few SE sites.  Edited in the standard SE `@match` set.

Comment: No idea why I never got to do this earlier but it’s done now in 1.5. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (v1.1.0)

Can the table be updated to show a cut-off line? Highlight the top 10 or put a (dotted?) line between the top 10 and the rest of the pack, to show who is going to go through without manually having to count.

Comment: Done! Added some styles and other stuff in v1.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) v1.4.0

Not matching HTTPS protocol requests. Simply change `http://...` to `*://...` in the `@match` annotations.

Comment: @poke The new vote feature uses HTTP, which fails on HTTPS :P Best to simply omit the protocol and host when doing AJAX to the same domain. (Line 69)

Comment: Haha, oops! Totally forgot about that – fixed now ^^

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (v1.4.6)

`'.votecell .vote-count-post'` needs to be changed to `'.votecell .js-vote-count'` for the new post layout on [L45](https://gist.github.com/poke/9058895#file-stackexchange-election-primary-counter-user-js-L45)

Comment: No idea how you found this out this early, but thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Found out while visiting the [previous election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10?tab=primary)